# remove price text from custom option from cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

I am using Magento 1.9.3.8, I need some customization in custom options text in cart page.

I want to remove custom option price from cart page.

[image]

I want just hide euro 23.99 and euro 12.00 from those custom options no any other extra things to do.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In custom option it is not showing price on cart.

Comment: Yes i want to hide price of custom options from cart page only.

Comment: I think default magento not displaying custom option price.

Comment: Yes, I m using mageworx custom options extension. so maybe the issue is from extension?

Comment: Welcome bro, happy to help you!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016775/removing-price-from-item-options-in-magento-checkout-cart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Edit below file and comment out to disable price content or edit price code as per requirement.

```
/app/code/community/MageWorx/CustomOptions/Helper/Product/Configurable.php
```